# How to convert HTTPS POST request to ESP8266 with API

Tags: arduino, http-post, alexa-skills-kit, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

**Hey y'all**

I got a Wemos D1 Mini and try to use the service <getnotify.me> to send notifications to my alexa directly from the microcontroller.
I cant get it to work i really tried everything but the api won't receive my data. Im either getting "-1" as response code or "307 - Temporary Redirect".
The API seems kinda easy and it also seems to work with http instead of https.

The developer needs the request in this format:

*Curl example:*

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"message":"your message here"}' --user nmxxxxxxxxxx:scxxxxxxxxxx https://api.getnotify.me/submit
```

*Python example:*

```
import requests

API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.getnotify.me/submit"
API_KEY = "nmxxxxxxxxxx"
API_SECRET = "scxxxxxxxxxx"

data = {'message':'your message here'}
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, json=data, auth=(API_KEY, API_SECRET))
print ("Response code: %d" %(r.status_code))
```

If i convert the Curl to a RAW Request it looks simle as this:

```
Authorization: Basic hu03NGGxMzGyZfVkOnTjTjAwZjIzBFWhNS==
Host: api.getnotify.me
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 31

{"message":"your message here"}
```

I already figured out, that the API Key which looks similar to this: "nmxxxxxxxxxx"
and the API secret: "scxxxxxxxxxx" need to be base64.

This is what i got so far:

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup() {

Serial.begin(115200);
WiFi.begin("ssid", "wifipw");

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { //Wait for the WiFI connection completion

delay(500);
Serial.println("Waiting for connection");

}

}

void loop() {

if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){ //Check WiFi connection status
  Serial.println("Connected");

  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("http://api.getnotify.me/submit");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  http.setAuthorization("Authorization", "Basic hu03NGGxMzGyZfVkOnTjTjAwZjIzBFWhNS==");
  int httpCode = http.POST("{\"message\":\"your message here\"}");
  String payload = http.getString();


 
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  Serial.println(payload);
  http.end();


}else{

Serial.print("Error in Wifi connection");

}

delay(30000); //Send a request every x seconds

}
```

In Python and via Curl it works like a charm (even with http instead of https!)

Do you have any idea how i can get this to work ? im really new to this arduino / esp8266 stuff and unfortunately there is no good examples in the webs and almost no documentation from the developer. but it should be pretty basic stuff. I tried a LOT of variations to the request like sending it all as headers or all in the POST but nothing works. what am i making wrong here?

Thank you so much for your help guys !!

Comment: Have you tried googling what "307 temporary redirect" means?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h it seems that you use `setAuthorization` incorrectly. The first parameter is username, second one is password:

```
http.setAuthorization("replace_username", "replace_password");
```

Comment: Thank you! Does the password need to be clear text or like in my example with base64 ?